# resize a div after setting innerHTML with mootools

Tags: css, ajax, html, mootools

I am using mootools 1.2 in a simple page. There's a div that displays a form (call it formdiv) that gets submitted via JS/ajax. The ajax request returns some data "confirmation message".

However, the formdiv div starts out maybe 500px high to accomodate the form elements. When the ajax request returns a variable-length return data ("confirmed for submission!") the div stays 500px high, leaving a lot of extra space.

My question is, is there a way to snap the div back to fit the new content after updating the content using innerHTML?

Thanks

EDITED: to add that the data returned by the Ajax call could be variable length-- so I can't assume it'll be a certain height and then reset the div to that height.

Comment: maybe try set min-height in css for that div?

Comment: Do you set a static height of your content `div` (in your case `500px`) because of you don't `div` should automatically resize to accommodate content?

Comment: Hi Robert-- no, there is no height set for the original formdiv.

Comment: yould you then provide a JSFiddle of your problem, because as you can see from my answer and JSFiddle, DIV resizes accordingly to content.

Answer (score 0):

If your `div` starts off with predefined height using CSS then all you should do is set its height to `auto` or clearing styles altogether when they were set inline.

Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWR5b/) (it works with jQuery here, but that doesn't matter when it comes to browser rendering `div` in question)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I realize that this is like a year late but I came across this question while attempting to find a script to do just this. This was a great starting point but I felt like I should share the method I choose to use:

1. Get the current actual height of `$('element')`.

   ```
   h.before = $('element').getSize().y;
   ```
2. Fx.Morph can't handle setting the `height` to `'auto'` so first you must set `height: 'auto'` on `$('element')` (in case it hasn't been already) and then set the html to the new content. This will allow you to get the new content's height.

   ```
   $('element').setStyle('height', 'auto');
   $('element').set('html', "Some other content.<br/>Very short.");
   h.after = $('element').getSize().y;
   ```
3. Reset the height and then start the Fx.Morph with `h.after`.

   ```
    $('element').setStyle('height', h.before);

    var myEffect = new Fx.Morph('element', {
        onComplete: function() {
            $('test').setStyle('height', 'auto');
        }
    });

    myEffect.start({'height': h.after});
   ```

You can check out the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cd4R9/

Please understand this is method is very basic and a lot would have to be done to make this site-ready. For example if your `$('element')` has padding, you will have to account for it or use the CSS property `box-sizing: border-box;`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh and I'm not sure if it's relevant but it **is** MooTools 1.2.5 compatible and higher (according to jsfiddle).